# How to bundle oracle data access dll?

Tags: .net, oracle, data-access

I use Oracle.DataAccess.dll for Oracle Version 10.2. with .NET.  I give the compiled application to the customer and it doesn't work for him because I am guessing ODP.NET is not on his machine.

I asked him to download and install it from Oracle, but that is not an option as he has to go through some approval process to get that done.

Is there an easy way to bundle just the dlls that are needed to get it to work?

Comment: Do you remember how you solved this or what the thread in the link below said? The link is dead and I'm stuck right where you were.

Answer (score 0):

ODP.NET is a thin .NET wrapper over Java classes, so bundling is a more difficult process. In addition, bundling may go against the Oracle EULAs, which could get you in trouble if you do it with quite a few customers. And, it is lot of work for just one.

You could set up a bootstrap program to have it auto load from oracle and install, but this may not get around his company's policy.